# Any reason not to use USE_ETAGS with CommonMiddleware in Django?

Tags: django, performance, http, caching, etag

The only reason I can think of is that calculating `ETag`'s might be expensive. If pages change very quickly, the browser's cache is likely to be invalidated by the `ETag`. In that case, calculating the `ETag` would be a waste of time. On the other hand, a giving a `304` response when possible minimizes the amount of time spent in transmission. What are some good guidelines for when `ETag`'s are likely to be a net winner when implemented with Django's `CommonMiddleware`?

Answer (score 4):

As with any caching mechanism, you will need to evaluate the trade-off between time spent manipulating the cache and bandwidth saved because of it.

As you say, if the response is changing often, ETags may not be very useful.  ETags are a method for caching entire responses, so if the response changes often not much is actually being cached.  However, I would guess that since ETags are in common use, browser implementations are resonably fast, and Django is probably fast enough too.

Perhaps there are other areas before the response that could benefit from caching with, for example, memcached.

Again, it will be beneficial to try profiling this with your real data rather than generalizing to "do or don't use it."

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle caching, and is often application specific, I propose in the  first scenarios how you might consider using `USE_ETAGS` from `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware`:

1. Split your application between cacheable and non-cacheable gunicorn instances. Wire the site up with reverse-proxy. Then continue with,
2. Writing code that invalidates cache on model saves. As a next step,
3. Write own custom caching middleware.

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand why you are looking for a reason not to do something. However your analysis is far from complete: conditional requests / 304 responses can actually make your application go significantly slower than it would if you strip the if-modified-since / if-none-match however they do keep search engines happy and are advantageous with server-server replication (e.g. on CDNs)

C.

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful for several reasons: 1) Your second sentence contains several ideas that could be split up into several sentences. 2) Why shouldn't I be looking for a good reason not to do something? 3) You state that 304 responses can make things slower without explaining why. While you mentioned something about not using if-modified-since (not sure how this applies to ETag's) and if-none-match headers, but that's not really much of an explanation. 4) "they do keep search engines happy"? Intriguing, but extremely vague.